# Getting the meaning of a comprehension

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

[image]

I have read this passage several time and I guess that the  summaries of the passage is in the last sentence I but couldn't grasp the  total real-meaning of the passage. Can you please paraphrase it to me in simple sentence so I will be able to answer the question very efficiently?
It will be helpful for me if you give me a clue that how to get the idea faster.

[image]

The given answer is the following.

[image]

Comment: What is the answer A and C?

Comment: No. I'm adding the answer.

Comment: I think this question needs to add some detail about what *you* think the answer is before we can help you. Rewriting the passage doesn't help you learn and isn't what this site is for.

Comment: @Matt We're stepping on each other's toes again! ;) At least I saw your comment first this time, haha, so I fail less. I agree, for questions about reading passages to be on-topic, you're going to have to tell us which answer you think it is and why (or why you don't think the correct answer makes sense). We can't simply rewrite the passage for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Comprehension is about two male subjects ( understand in normal language two males)  passing by two stages : 1) Wire Suspension bridge 2) Low solid bridge and how they get aroused sexually.

1) When two males passed by a wire suspension bridge, they got more sexually aroused as compared to the others passed by low solid bridge.

2) The two males passed by wire suspension bridge contacted the female interviewer even after the interview.

3) Males that passed by wire suspension bridge had highest fear reactions such as increase in heart rate. This means when a man is completely sexually aroused his rate of heart beats increases.

4)Males that passed by low solid bridge were less sexually aroused as they considered that lady as unattractive or less attractive.

5) Conclusion : If the lady is attractive, the arousal can be interpreted as attraction and if the lady is unattractive or less attractive, the arousal can be interpreted as repulsion but here none of them is shown (i.e. the true cause is masked).

I think you will understand this experiment in a better way from this link : 
http://www.psychologyconcepts.com/dutton-and-aron-suspension-bridge-experiment/

Answer (score 1):

- Dutton and Aron conducted an experiment where they asked a set of people to do a dangerous task and another set of people to do a less dangerous task. After these tasks the guys who had done the dangerous tasks showed more signs of being attracted to the opposite sex.
- From these results Dutton and Aron concluded that the higher heart rate and other fear reactions due to the dangerous tasks were wrongly attributed to sexual attraction by the human mind.
- But later another researcher named Foster found that dangerous activities make people either like something more or hate something more. So if you saw a girl who looks good you would feel that she was very good looking. Likewise if you saw a girl who looks bad you would feel she was very bad looking.